# Syntax Error when using Gulp to compile React in ES6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gulp, ecmascript-6

When I try to compile the following code using React I get the error below. I don't see the issue in such a simple program and the example code compiles correctly when I clone the git repo.

main.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import HelloWorld from './components/helloworld';
//import HelloWorld from './hello-world-es5';

React.render(
    <HelloWorld phrase="ES6"/>,
    document.body
);
```

HelloWorld:

```
import React from 'react';


class HelloWorld extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <h1>Hello from {this.props.phrase}!</h1>;
    }
}

export default HelloWorld;
```

error:

```
SyntaxError: /Users/**/**/**/**/js/main.js: Unexpected token (7:4)
  5 | 
  6 | ReactDOM.render(
> 7 |     <HelloWorld phrase="ES6"/>,
    |     ^
  8 |     document.body
  9 | );
    at Parser.pp.raise 
Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: How are you compiling it?

Comment: Gulp with babelify. I can post the gulp dile if necessary

Comment: How have you configured `babelify` at this point? If you're using the newest version, you'll need to enable `es2015` and `react` as two separate presets.

Comment: I recommend you switch to the superior webpack, aside from that it seems like you didn't set up your compiler properly to detect and compile jsx

Comment: loganfsmyth you were right. This requirement does not seem to have made it out to the documentation at large. If you would like, you can retype this as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: Dominic Tobias, what would you say are the advantages of Webpack over Browserify? It seems the field of JS compilers/loaders is a difficult one to navigate right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into this problem while using the latest versions of babelify, browserify, and react.  You need to specify a presets configuration for the latest versions of babelify.  An es6 gulp task might look something like this:

```
'use strict';

import browserify from 'browserify';

import babelify from 'babelify';
import reactPreset from 'babel-preset-react';
import es2015Preset from 'babel-preset-es2015';

import source from 'vinyl-source-stream';
import buffer from 'vinyl-buffer';

import gulp from 'gulp';
import gutil from 'gulp-util';
import uglify from 'gulp-uglify';
import sourcemaps from 'gulp-sourcemaps';

import config from '../config'; //externalized json config file

gulp.task('compile', function () {
    var b = browserify({
        entries: config.entries,
        debug: true,
        transform: [babelify.configure({'presets': [reactPreset, es2015Preset]})]
    });

    return b.bundle()
        .pipe(source(config.source))
        .pipe(buffer())
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init({loadMaps: true}))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .on('error', gutil.log)
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.dest));
});
```

Note that the browserify is being passed a configuration object that contains the transform property for containing the babelify transform that is also being configured with a object.  The babelify configuration object contains the presets.  You should also npm install the presets that you wish to use.  You can read more about this at https://github.com/babel/babelify#options.

One other thing that I noticed is that you don't mention your Reactjs version.  The latest is 0.14.2 which made some significant changes over 0.13.3. Using the latest you would also need react-dom and use that as the mount point for your component to the DOM.