# Gulp, Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gulp

I'm trying to make a simple contactlist using react, when I execute "gulp" command everything's fine but when I go to chrome it doesn't show anything. The chrome console says:

> "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <" at my main.js:10 file

but I think it's fine.

This is my main.js file:

```
var App = require('./components/App');
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
var AppAPI = require('./utils/appAPI.js');


AppAPI.getContacts();

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

And this is is my gulpfile.js

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var browserify = require('browserify');
var reactify = require('reactify'); // Converts jsx to js
var source = require('vinyl-source-stream'); // Converts string to a stream

gulp.task('browserify', function(){
    browserify('./src/js/main.js')
        .transform('reactify')
        .bundle()
        .pipe(source('main.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/js'));
});

gulp.task('copy', function(){
    gulp.src('src/index.html')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
    gulp.src('src/css/*.*')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/css'));
    gulp.src('src/js/vendors/*.*')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/js'));
});

gulp.task('default', ['browserify', 'copy'], function(){
    return gulp.watch('src/**/*.*', ['browserify', 'copy']);
});
```

This is my Index.html file

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>ReactApp</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app" class="container"></div>

    <script src="js/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

App.js is

```
var React = require('react');
var AppActions = require('../actions/AppActions');
var AppStore = require('../stores/AppStore');
var AddForm = require('./AddForm.js');

function getAppState(){
    return {
        contacts: AppStore.getContacts()
    }
}

var App = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function(){
        return getAppState();
    },

    componentDidMount: function(){
        AppStore.addChangeListener(this._onChange);
    },

    componentUnmount: function(){
        AppStore.removeChangeListener(this._onChange);
    },

    render: function(){
        console.log(this.state.contacts);
        return(
            <div>
                <AddForm />
            </div>
        );
    },

    // Update view state when change is received
    _onChange: function(){
        this.setState(getAppState());
    }
});

module.exports = App;
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to attach app.js, fixed

Comment: @David React allows for inline markup (JSX). The problem here is clearly that Gulp doesn't know that.

Comment: That's JSX in React - what the reactify plugin is presumably trying to remunge.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Syntax Error when using Gulp to compile React in ES6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33429119/syntax-error-when-using-gulp-to-compile-react-in-es6)

Answer (score 1):

Your gulp tasks need some work:
You need to use gulp.src to *get* your main.js file. then, transform is an option of gulp-browserify, not something you want to pipe your stream on, same for bundle.

```
gulp.task('scripts', function () {
  return gulp.src('./assets/js/main.js')
    .pipe(browserify({
      transform: [reactify]
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./static/js'));
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You are having the same issue as the person on this post, [Syntax Error when using Gulp to compile React in ES6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33429119/syntax-error-when-using-gulp-to-compile-react-in-es6)

You can fix it changing the configuration on your gulp tasks